# Delete from MySQL in javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this list of items obtained from a MySQL database. I am trying to create some functionality to make the user delete any item by clicking on a link that performs a simple delete query from the MySQL and at the same time removes the item dynamically from the list without refreshing the page.

I am a novice when it comes to JS and such.

My Markup:

```
<!-- the following content comes from MySQL -->
<div class="item">
    <!-- div content -->
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="someFunction()">Delete</a>
<div>

<div class="item">
    <!-- div content -->
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="someFunction()">Delete</a>
</div>
```

I don't know what shoud go into `somefunction()`, but I want it to delete ONLY the content from it's corresponding DIV from the database, and remove or hide it from the user without refreshing the page.

Comment: You need an ajax request.

Comment: You need to break this down into a server-side function, and a client-side operation which calls that via an ajax request. The php/mysql operation is one issue, the ajax request is the other. It's useful to narrow this down to one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a few things to handle this:
A. the mysql id for each div item
B. an ajax call to perform the delete
C. a hide or destroy action on the div itself

A: First, get the mysql id into the div item.  I typically end up using data-id or something similar on the closest item to the action. This minimizes the jquery logic.

```
<!-- the following content comes from MySQL -->
<div class="item">
    <!-- div content -->
    <a class="delete-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="<?php echo mysql_id; ?>">Delete</a>
<div>
```

B: the php side of the AJAX call:
  is a standard php file that accepts the id query string, safely escapes it, ideally checks permissions, then deletes from mysql.

B: I prefer to use jquery class handlers to make it easy to change the behavior in a central place.  Notice I added the 'class="delete-item"' and removed the onchange handler in the code above.  In this section we'll write a simple jquery AJAX delete handler on the delete-item class:

C: in the ajax success handler go ahead and hide the div.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.delete-item').click(function (e) {
    itemid = $(this).attr('data-id');
    parentdiv = $(this).parent();

    $.ajax({
      url:      '/ajax/delete-item.php?id='+itemid,
      dataType: "json",
      error:     function(e) { alert("An error occurred deleting this item.") },
      success:   function(data) {
          parentdiv.hide();
      }

    });
});
```

Comment: It didn't quite work the way I hoped, but thanks! I can take it from here I think

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with AJAX?  Forgive me if you know this already, but in case you don't:

Ajax posts data to an external php file, which processes the data it receives, and sends back an answer.  It looks like this:

FILE #1:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#Sel').change(function() {
                    var opt = $(this).val();
                    var someelse = 'Hello';
                    var more_stuff = 'Goodbye';
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "receiving_file.php",
                        data: 'selected_opt=' + opt + '&something_else=' +someelse+'&more_stuff='+more_stuff,
                        success:function(data){
                            alert('This was sent back: ' + data);
                            //Next line adds the data from PHP into the DOM
                            $('#somediv').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

<div id="somediv">
    <select id = "Sel">
        <option value ="Song1">default value</option>
        <option value ="Song2">Break on through</option>
        <option value ="Song3">Time</option>
        <option value ="Song4">Money</option>
        <option value="Song5">Saucerful of Secrets</option>
    </select>
</div><!-- #somediv -->
```

FILE #2: receiving_file.php

```
<?php
    //This is where you get the data from the browser
    $recd = $_POST['selected_opt'];
    $uid = $_POST['someelse'];

    //This is where you do your MYSQL database changes, for example:
    //mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `fav_song`='$recd' WHERE `user_id` = '$uid'");

    //When done, you can echo back some new HTML, like this:

    $r  = '<h1>You chose:</h1>';
    $r .= '<p>' . $recd . '</p>';  //adds to $r

    echo $r;  //Use ECHO to send data back to the browser
```

---

The above is a fully working, stand-alone, copy-pastable example. Just copy/paste it into two files:

1. index.html (or test.php, or whatever), and
2. **receiving_file.php**  -- if you wish to rename this file, you must also change the name in the AJAX code block in file 1.